# Doctrine make:migration unknown database type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to start using Doctrine, but I encountered a problem when I created entity through `php bin/console make:entity`, then I tried to make migration with `php bin/console make:migration` but I get this error message:

> Uknown database type _int4 requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform may not support it.

I am using postgres 9.4 and doctrine 2.6

Comment: AFAIK, Postgres has `int4`, so, indeed, what is `_int4`? Try searching across your entity files for the string...

Comment: Nothing, I tried to search in the entities that I have created and trying to migrate them and also in my database schema that I am using. There was only 3 places where int4 was used, but not _int4

Comment: Well, for now I just added `$dbType = $dbType === '_int4' ?  'int4' : $dbType ` to AbstractPlatform where it was throwing the error and it looks like it is working

Comment: See this issue comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/19#issuecomment-195538120

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In symfony `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` you can just map the type to data type that you want.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        mapping_types:
            _int4: string
```